# Best server configuration for Magento 2 small application

Tags: magento2, php, linux, ubuntu

We are developing one small application of electronics in magento 2 community version.

Now we are planning to publish this site so which server/configuration is best for this kind of site

So please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

**My recommendations:**

1. Use Apache2 or Nginx (Both web servers, in their latest versions, can compete with each other in most areas)
2. Use php-fpm and opcache for improving performance
3. Use varnish cache
4. Use Mariadb
5. Minify and Merge js and css
6. Use PHP version 7.1.X

If you achieve **Time To First Byte** below **500ms**, your server configuration seems good.

If you have any other doubts, please feel free to mention in the comment section.

Comment: There are many host provider, But which is best for us

Host gator, amajon, godaddy?

Comment: better ssd server at soyoustart.com